# How to scrape/pinch a mesh in the center?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I am a noob when it comes to sculpting in blender. I am trying to recreate a similar shape to this image I found on Pinterest:

[image]

What tools would work best for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the functionality you are looking for is called radial symmetry:

[image]

It can be used on any brush, this here is Clay strips

Setting can be found here:

[image]

Changing these 3 values will give you more copies of your brush in radial array, I have used 22 brushes on axis X to model first image

Comment: Does the mesh need to be subdivided a few times before doing this?

Comment: it sure does, you should start with few subdivides and subdivide more(or use Dyntopo) to sculpt smaller details... you need to have topology for sculpting, the image I used was a cube subdivided 5 times